# How to make edittext in Android scrollable?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating a dynamic layout that contains an edit text. I want to make this edit text scrollable.

```
questionEntry.setMaxLines(1);
questionEntry.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
questionEntry.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Using this code I made my edit text scrollable. But the problem is when I am typing something. If it reaches the end of the edit text, it will stop typing my text and not automatically jump to the next line. If I press the enter key, it will jump. I want to make it automatic.

Comment: Why are you doing `setMaxLines(1);` ?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me setting these methods programmatically.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
questionEntry.setScroller(new Scroller(myContext)); 
questionEntry.setMaxLines(1); 
questionEntry.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
questionEntry.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

i made some changes in my previous code.
above posted is my new code.

it s working...thanks for all

Comment: I don't think the setScroller() call is necessary - just the call to setMovementMethod().

Comment: This doesn't work for EditTexts with setKeyListener(null), or at all.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me setting these methods programmatically. I also tried nesting the EditText view in a NestedScrollView widget without success.

Comment: not work, down vote.

Answer (score 41):

I know this question has already got an answer, but if you wish to get the same result via XML, change

```
android:inputType="text"
```

to

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

for a vertically scrollable EditText.

Answer (score 28):

Try this, Hope it Helps

```
questionEntry.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.inputFormComments) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Working fine now able to scroll

Comment: Thank you very much! Works. Don't understand, why it is so hard to make EditText scrollable...

Comment: should have gotten more votes, of all the things this worked for me

Comment: Perfect. By the way, if your EditText is in a RecyclerView you can add an OnFocusChangedListener to the ET and do this "recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(!hasFocus));" It will stop the recyclerview scrolling when you want the edittext to be scrolling.

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

Just let it know that it should act that way by:

```
android:isScrollContainer="true"
```