# Android EditText Vertical Scrolling Problem

Tags: android

I'm using an EditText of some predefined size, however when a user enters more text then fits in the text box, they aren't able to scroll the text with touch. Scrolling does work with a trackball.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making TextView Scrollable in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you would like the text to scroll horizontally, define in your EditText XML tag:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

If you would like a vertical scroll, define in your EditText XML tag:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: when i am set the max line more than one then it's not working !

Comment: Hmm @yesterday this answer was given quite a long time ago. I no longer do Android development, so I'm not really in a place where I can help out. If anyone has any suggestions to his comment - happy to update my answer or delete if there's a better one!

Answer (score 15):

make the changes like the following to get scroller in your EditText

```
questionEntry.setScroller(new Scroller(myContext)); 
questionEntry.setMaxLines(1); 
questionEntry.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
questionEntry.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

[How to make edittext in Android scrollable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831392/how-to-make-edittext-in-android-scrollable)

Donot forget to vote if you feel my response is helpful for you

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 10):

> In java

```
 EditText dwEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DwEdit);       
 dwEdit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (view.getId() ==R.id.DwEdit) {
                view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                switch (event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

> In xml

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/DwEdit"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minLines="10"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:inputType="textCapSentences">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A simple way to do scroll-able text in edittext if parent is NestedScrollView or ScrollView**

**XML code**

```
android:gravity="top"
android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
android:lines="5"
```

**Use below code for Kotlin**

```
    editText.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        if (v.id == R.id.editText) {
            v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
            when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
            }
        }
        false
    }
```