# scroll edittext content on change of seek bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-edittext

> i have searched a lot but can't find any thing which help me to know
>   How to scroll edit text content on change of seek bar based on the
>   current position and progress.
>
> Please help.....

```
public void startScrollingText() {

    timer = new Timer();

    System.out.println(CurrentValues.cur_script_speed
            + "its a current speed");
    script_speed = (int) (100 - CurrentValues.cur_script_speed);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    final Layout layout = script.getLayout(); // System.out.println(textview.getScrollY());
                    if (layout != null) {
                        int scrollDelta = layout.getLineBottom(script
                                .getLineCount() - 1)
                                - script.getScrollY()
                                - script.getHeight();
                        // System.out.println(scrollDelta);
                        if (scrollDelta > 0)
                            script.scrollTo(0, script.getScrollY() + 5);
                        // else
                        // script.scrollTo(0, 0);
                        System.out.println(CurrentValues.cur_script_speed
                                + " current speed");
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }, 1000, script_speed + 1);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get anything like that??

Comment: i just got how to use seekbar listener i tried whole day but that is not working properly.. edit box not scrolling as i change the seek bar

Comment: Look at the answer below, Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have got SeekBar working and EditText initialized then you must know that the values would change with the method below.

And this is what you should do,

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
               yourEditText.setText("changing values are "+progress);
            }
```

Comment: thanks but i need to scroll edittext content... plese help if you know how to scroll edit text

Comment: Call the above function inside onprogresschanged as I have shown above http://stackoverflow.com/a/6124165/1503130  this might solve your problem. But all you need to do inside the above function.