# Vertical scrollbar in multiline EditText

Tags: android

I have used table layout and given vertical scrollbar to it. the table layout is having a table row of edittext whose input type is textMultiLine i want to add vertical scrollbar to it. For this i have used,

```
   edittext_level_desc.setScroller(new Scroller(getApplicationContext()));
   edittext_level_desc.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

But its not working.

Comment: search still works, FYI. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123973/android-edittext-vertical-scrolling-problem/6124165#6124165

Comment: I have referred this link only but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

Check out these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124165/944070
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233683/944070

If any of them work, but it is quite difficult and annoying to apply scrollers in scrollers you may need a custom view, and also a custom scroll based on gestures or touch events.

I suggest change your layout in order to avoid that. It may be more helpful to have an EditText not scrolling expanding.

Comment: can u provide me some links for gesture or touch events for this?