# Android EditText: only scroll horizontally

Tags: android

I have defined the 2 EditTexts in a LinearLayout:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:minHeight="120dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eT_eingabe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:width="100dp"
                android:background="#00464646"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minHeight="55sp"
                app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
                app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
                app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eT_ausgabe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:width="100dp"
                android:background="#00464646"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minHeight="55sp"
                app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
                app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
                app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

In code I only change their typeface and textcolor:

```
view.setTextColor(tc);
view.setTypeface(tf);
```

Both have the identical code (except the id) and should only have one line and scroll vertically. 
eT_eingabe does so. eT_ausgabe always has one line, but on a device with API 21 (Huawei Honor 7, real device) still does allow to scroll vertically (The user can move the text slightly up and down). On API 24 (Pixel 3, emulator) everything works fine.

**My question is:** how can I prevent the edittext eT_ausgabe from scrolling up and down?

Comment: why do you set match_parent for the height in both of your views in a vertical linear layout? Is that intended?

Comment: @Nikos Hidalgo Im new to android. I want both EditText to have half of the height of the parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all responds!
I solved my problem like this. I created a parent Linear Layout over above the Linear Layout and limited its height to 150sp. My solution looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/m_display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/displayshape"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/m_eT_Eingabe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:width="100dp"
            android:background="#00464646"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minHeight="55sp"

            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/m_eT_Ausgabe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:width="100dp"
            android:background="#00464646"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minHeight="55sp"

            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable editText scrolling use this code :

```
eT_ausgabe.setMovementMethod(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ... the problem is that this disables all scrolling, but i want to only disable vertical scrolling.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123973/android-edittext-vertical-scrolling-problem