# android edittext is not scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

I have edittext. Now my edittext is wrapping content, i dont know why, i want it stay same size but be scrollable(vertical).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewFull"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="10"
    />

 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/editTextFull"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:clickable="false"
 android:ems="10"
 android:lines="1"
 android:maxLines="5"
 android:cursorVisible="false"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
 android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
  >

 <requestFocus />
 </EditText>


</LinearLayout>
```

And in java i set text with `setText`

Comment: please submit the complete layout file , but I think that the layout_weight is causing you the problem

Comment: @Saksak i submit complete layout file

Comment: have you tried to remove the weight and check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `EditText` in `ScrollView` or take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831392/how-to-make-edittext-in-android-scrollable) thread to make it scrollable programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFull"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
     >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set your `layout_height="wrap_content"`?

Comment: I just realized that I have my whole layout within a `ScrollView`. Try one of those answers. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Emsg"
        android:hint="@string/texthint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#02960B"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</ScrollView>
```

i have set the height by `android:layout_height="200dp"`