# Scrollable EditText at AndroidStudio

Tags: android-edittext

so I'm trying to create a simple scrollable **layout** and a scrollable **edittext's** within the layout.
Scrollable layout works perfectly with ScrollView layout.
I've read about EditText scroll to implement this code -

```
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="10"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

But when I run the app on my phone and I try to scroll up within the EditText, it scrolls the layout (Using the ScrollView layout), instead of scrolling the EditText.

Anyway suggestions?
Thanks alot!

Comment: You can refer the following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831392/how-to-make-edittext-in-android-scrollable

Answer (score 0):

I think by not setting the height of the EditText to wrap content will help you.
Either try setting height to match parent or set height in DP's.

Comment: Nope.. it doesn't fix at all.