# EditText cannot be scrollable

Tags: java, android

As per answer here [How to make edittext in Android scrollable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831392/how-to-make-edittext-in-android-scrollable), why my interface became like that?

XML Coding:-

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/contactMsg"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_clipboards"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Message"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:maxLines = "5"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Java Coding:-

```
    yourMessage.setScroller(new Scroller(this));
    yourMessage.setMaxLines(1);
    yourMessage.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    yourMessage.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

My interface became like this:-

[image: My Interface]

Comment: can you please share full code.

Comment: @MehulKabaria the coding is too long, so I cant paste it all here...

Comment: If you are using `Activity` then pass `this` at `myContext`

Comment: Did you initialize `myContext` ? Where are you adding `EditText` in `Activity`? or `Fragment`?

Comment: Ohhh I'm using all in Activity @AbuYousuf

Comment: @MehulKabaria is like this, Context myContext = this; ????

Comment: yap initialize `myContext` with `this` because `Activity` itself `Context`

Comment: I already edit my question and the interface go wrong.... OMG, I just want the editText to be scroll-able...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank God! I got it.. I just have to throw away this coding in my XML Coding:-

```
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLines = "5"
```

And put this coding:-

```
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

[image: It works!]